# Cant connect to SQL server only from my app on my machine

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a very simple app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
            connection.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(connection.State.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Running the app gives me an exception

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Inner exception:
>
> Access is denied
>
> Stack Trace
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at TestConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in p:\Projects\TestConsoleApplication1\TestConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 17

This app works on other peoples machines. And on my machine typing the following into c# interactive works:

```
 Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.2.20906.1 
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
  connection.Open();
  connection.State
Open
```

Also the connection seems to work if it is made from a WCF service running on my machine. I am able to connect from my machine using SQL Server Management Studio, and the Visual Studio Server Explorer

My first thought was a firewall issue on my machine. I have disabled the firewall though, and I am still having the issue.

Comment: The Connection DataSource is different in the interactive is different to the code above (SQL vs SQL2012DEV) - is that the issue?

Comment: Are you using SQL Express? Looks like a configuration issue. In Express, network access is disabled by default.

Comment: How many computers have successfully connected to SQL Server?

Comment: You are trying to connect by windows service account does sql server support connection with windows?

Comment: on "SQL vs SQL2012DEV" that is not the issue, was just checking that the same problem happend on the dev and production servers.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the application was running on the P: drive which is a network drive.  Copying things over the the C: drive, and it works.

Here is a question where someone had the same problem: [‘error 26 - error locating server’ when launching C# exe located on NW drive from Win7; MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356401/error-26-error-locating-server-when-launching-c-sharp-exe-located-on-nw-driv)